# Interacting with a command line process

Tags: java, windows, process

I need to interact with a command line process, e.g. diskpart on windows. The problem: `input.readLine()` in the following sample leads to a blocking while.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\system32\\diskpart.exe");                      
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

    // read #1 code position
    String line = null;
    while((line = input.readLine())!= null)
        System.out.println(line);

    // code position #2
    System.out.println("This line is never executed");   

    output.write("list disk" + System.lineSeparator());
    output.flush(); // important
}
```

The output (from read #1 code position) is

```
Microsoft DiskPart-Version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
Auf Computer: MYPC
```

This is correct, however after that nothing happens, e.g. code position #2

```
System.out.println("This line is never executed");
```

is never reached. Can anyone tell me, why and how to fix this? Thanks!

**Update:**

Trying to read byte by byte also seems not to work? ):

```
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    int mychar = -1;

    while((mychar = input.read()) != -1)
        System.out.println(mychar);

    System.out.println("This line is never executed");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the next thing Diskpart does is show the prompt, which doesn't include a newline:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: PCNAME

DISKPART> _
```

So your code sits there waiting for the newline, which never appears.

You need to change your code to send the "list disk" command at the right time.

Comment: In other words, work off InputStreamReader directly and read the characters one-by-one.   Don't wrap it in a BufferedReader.

Comment: Thank you both, I tried reading character by character (please see update on my original post), but same problem ): any hint? :-)

Comment: You're still waiting for end-of-stream, i.e., for input.read() to return -1.  That's not going to happen until `diskpart` exits, which won't happen until you send an `exit` command.  Instead, exit the loop when you see the `>` character.

Answer (score 1):

[Diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) has an interactive console that requires input from the user. Attempting to read its output like this:

```
while((line = input.readLine())!= null)
      System.out.println(line);
```

will cause you to wait indefinitely as the application itself requires input.

You need to wait for input first from the windows command so you need to add **`CMD /C`** to your command.

As `diskpart` is interactive, you could try running your list command as a script, so you would have instead:

```
String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "C:\\Windows\\system32\\diskpart.exe", "/s", "diskpart.txt"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

with `diskpart.txt` containing:

```
list disk
```

I recommend you getting this working in a standard batch file first though to check that the output is correct.

Comment: Thanks, how would you read the individual bytes? Please see my updated post above (that new code unfortunately has the same problem).